# Get java version from batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, version

How to get java version and want to get '6' out of java version from batch file.
I tried below script, but it didn't work.

```
    REM check java exists using JAVA_HOME system variable

if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
ECHO Installing java
start /w jdk.exe /s
SETX -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31"
ECHO java installed successfully
) ELSE (
ECHO checking java version
goto check_java_version
)

REM check java version using JAVA_HOME system variable
:check_java_version
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -version 2^>^&1') do set "jver=%%j%%k%%l%%m"
echo %jver%
```

JAVA_HOME has "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31" value.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %j in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do @set "jver=%j%k%l%m"
```

This will store the java version into **`jver`** variable and as integer
And you can use it for comparisons .E.G

```
if %jver% LSS 16000 echo not supported version
```

.You can use more major version by removing %k and %l and %m.This command prompt version.

***For .bat use this:***

```
@echo off
PATH %PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\
for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do set "jver=%%j%%k%%l%%m"
```

According to my tests this is the fastest way to get the java version from bat (as it uses only internal commands and not external ones as `FIND`,`FINDSTR` and does not use `GOTO` which also can slow the script). Some JDK vendors does not support `-fullversion` switch or their implementation is not the same as this one provided by Oracle (better avoid them).

Comment: How to print jver value. i tried with echo %jver%. its not working

Comment: try with ***PATH %PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\\*** before the for loop

Comment: getting error: it says *path is not a command. then for echo %jver% it says echo is off. i updated my question above. gave full script. just check it out plz.

Comment: remove the *.The bolding left one asteriks here...Will edit the answer

Comment: java.exe is not in the path. what is the result if you just write %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe /?

Comment: your path should have %JAVA_HOME%\bin.You can check if `java -fullversion` generates some output.If you have the java.exe in the path i should rewrite my answer to use only `-version` switch.

Comment: here is my code: for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('java -version 2^>^&1') do set "jver=%%j"   i got 6 out of the version. how to get "0_31"?

Comment: you must use `-fullversion` instead `-version`

Comment: `for /f eol^=J^ tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('java -version 2^>^&1') do set "jver=%%j.%%k.%%l_%%m"`

Comment: I'd like to use a custom java path, like this: `for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %j in ('path\to\jre\java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do @set "jver=%j%k%l%m"`. How do I get this working?

Comment: @s1ice - it should work in the way you posted it.But some vendors have different implementations of `-fullversion` . What is the problem with the line you posted? Is it ran from batch file or from command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `awk`:

```
>java -fullversion 2>&1|awk "{print $NF}"
"1.7.0_21-b11"

>java -fullversion 2>&1|awk -F\" "{print $(NF-1)}"
1.7.0_21-b11
```

---

Script example:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR /f %%a IN ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1^|awk "{print $NF}"') DO SET "javaversion=%%a"
IF DEFINED javaversion (ECHO java version: %javaversion%) ELSE ECHO java NOT found
```

output is: `java version: "1.7.0_21-b11"`
[awk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)

Comment: @BobbyRachel script inserted.

Answer (score 1):

it will be surly idiot but why do not just print JAVA_HOME path ?

Answer (score 0):

it should be java -version // if environment path is already set

or %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -version //if path is not already set

Answer (score 0):

Within a block statement, %var% would be echoed as the value of `var` BEFORE the block was entered.

Move the `echo` outside of the block or echo `%%g` or `call echo %%javaver%%` or invoke `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion` and `echo !javaver!`