# check java is installed on windows system

Tags: java, jvm, c++builder

How to check, java is installed on windows system and get fullpath from jvm.dll on client folder?

I used this code, but i dont know how to retrive the current version

```
TRegistry* reg = new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
reg->RootKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
reg->Access = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
bool openResult = reg->OpenKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment", true);
if(!openResult) // cannot create registry keys, use default values
    return;
if(!reg->ValueExists("CurrentVersion")) //it's not exist CuurentVersion
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think writing some code or anything like that is needed to see if java is installed.
To see if its installed on windows just go to `C:\Program Files\Java` if that directory exists then you have java, if its installed on a different directory look in windows programs and it should show if java is installed, if not then you most likely don't have java.
Use [this](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml) link to see what version you have, but it is recommended to always get the latest version.

Hope this helps, Luke

Edit:

If you want to see if java is installed on another computer programmatically try using a .bat file to see, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714681/get-java-version-from-batch-file) link should help.
or use [jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) to build the jar into an .exe, with this, if java is not installed it will prompt the user to install java.

Comment: He wants to see if a user X has Java installed, not him.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a system "Java -version" command from your code. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c) is an example for C++. To find the version you just need to parse the result you get, if you get. The String result would provide the information you required.

[image]

Meanwhile, to find the path i believe you can do it by iterating through environmental variables and look for JAVA_HOME.

Comment: I would opt for using `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` and `JNIEnv::GetVersion()` instead of parsing a command-line output.  And you don't need to "iterate" through environment variables, most platforms provide a way to query the value of a specific variable by its name.  On Windows, it is [`GetEnvironmentVariable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188.aspx). However, Windows does not use `JAVA_HOME` (at least, there is no `JAVA_HOME` variable on my system, even though Java is installed).

Comment: regarding JAVA_HOME you are right: its not guaranteed to work. the first suggestion is quite a valid one, so i believe you should post it as one alternative of possible solutions.